# PostgreSQL query to aggregate value of a column based on combination of values of two other columns, regardless of order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to perform an operation that aggregates the values of one column based on combination of values in two other columns irrespective of which column they show up in. For example, given this table:

```
a b 10.0 <-
b c 5.0 
c d 1.0 
b a 20.0 <-
```

I would like to return the following (if the aggregation I want to do is a sum):

```
a b 30.0 <-
b c 5.0 
c d 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` in **both** column selection **and** `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(col1, col2) AS col1,
    GREATEST(col1, col2) AS col2,
    SUM(col3) AS sum_c
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 
  LEAST(col1, col2), 
  GREATEST(col1, col2)
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

Try out on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ooezD_dK) based on your data.

There is no need for `CASE WHEN` here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into the grouping and ordering functions, this is an example of how you can use group by and order by to achieve what you are trying to do -

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a <= b THEN a ELSE b END AS col1,
    CASE WHEN a <= b THEN b ELSE a END AS col2,
    SUM(c) AS sum_c
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1, col2
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

`GROUP BY` clause groups the rows by the unique combination of `col1` and `col2`, `ORDER BY` clause sorts the result in a specified order and `CASE` statements to ensure that the values in columns A and B are ordered consistently so that 'a b' and 'b a' are treated as the same combination and finally, `SUM` function to aggregate the values in column C

Comment: This will not produce the correct result, please try out.